# continuously check if something exists and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

The content on my page is loaded via AJAX (it's a step by step process) and I need to check if a specific div exists.

That specific div appears after few clicks. I have to mention that I don't know the number of clicks.

How can I continuously check if the div exists till it finds it and after it finds it do to something?

**Later edit: 
How can I continuously check till a specific div doesn't exist and do something after that. More exactly the div is there, but after a few ajax calls it gets removed.**

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that I never know exactly after which number of clicks it appears.

Comment: you can try setInterval

Comment: how exactly can I use this?

Comment: Do you control the ajax? Or is it a third party script? If so best solution is very simple

Comment: I am controlling in it, if controlling means that I have to click on something in order to receive the content which contains that specific div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't control the AJAX load, this might be a solution for you.

*Note: As commented by @metarmask, [`DOMSubtreeModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) is deprecated but has still a better cross browser coverage (at the time this answer were posted) than the newer [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (provided a sample of that in the end of this answer).*

Use `DOMSubtreeModified` event, which will allow any method, click or what ever, to add (or remove) content and it will be detected.

```
(function(doc,found) {
  window.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {

    var yourdiv = doc.querySelector("#yourdiv");

    if(found && !yourdiv){
      // Was there but is gone, do something
      found = false;

    }

    if(yourdiv){
      // Found it, do something
      found = true;

    }

  }, false);
})(document,false);
```

It work like this, when content is inserted (or removed) the event fires and check for your specific div.

It also has benefits of not being called every *nn* second, like a timer, nor being processed on every click, only when DOM changed.

---

An equivalent sample using the newer [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) method would be

```
(function(doc,found) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

          var yourdiv = doc.querySelector("#yourdiv");

          if(found && !yourdiv){
            // Was there but is gone, do something
            found = false;

          }

          if(yourdiv){
            // Found it, do something
            found = true;

          }

        });
    });
    observer.observe(doc, { childList: true, subtree: true });
})(document,false);
```

Comment: [The `DOMSubtreeModified` event is deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: Still over complicated and not 100% browser coverage if OP controls the ajax

Comment: @charlietfl: Agree fully ... still, we don't know yet, and for someone else than the OP, who don't control the insert, this is a good alternative.

Comment: right...but could be XY problem if OP does control it. Have tried asking myself but no response

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah .. it will, so will make a note in my answer, to favor the ajax input if possible

Comment: There's an even more complex approach but would be fully browser compliant assuming not using jsonp and that is overload the XMLHttpRequest object. I'm not going to write that one up though

Comment: @LGSon  
I am controlling it, if controlling means that I have to click on something in order to receive the content which contains that specific div.

Comment: @LGSon also, how can I do it the other way around, to check till the div doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @agis It depends on what you mean with "check till div doesn't exists anymore"? .. My suggested solution run the code once when found your div after an insert, and can easily do the opposite when something was deleted, so to get a good answer for that, you have to extend your question explaining that.

Answer (score 6):

Use setInterval:

```
var divCheckingInterval = setInterval(function(){
    // Find it with a selector
    if(document.querySelector("#element")){
        console.log("Found!");
        clearInterval(divCheckingInterval);
        // Do something
    }
}, 500);
```

A better way to do something when the div appears using `MutationObserver`s:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        for(var i = 0;i < mutation.addedNodes.length;i++){
            if(mutation.addedNodes[i].id === "the-element"){
                console.log("Found!");
                observer.disconnect();
                // Do something
            }
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector("#parent-of-where-the-div-is-going-to-appear"), {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

The function in the MutationObserver constructor will only get triggered when a element is added or removed from the element you specified which is better for performance.

Comment: How can I do it the other way around, when a specific div doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Replace `addedNodes` with `removedNodes`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` to periodically check for your div (500 ms below). When its found, take the action and remember to clear the interval.

```
t = setInterval(function(){
    var mydiv = $('div.myclass');
    if (mydiv.length > 0) {
        console.log('Div exists');
        clearInterval(t);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: So basically this is continuosly searches for that div for 500 miliseconds and if it doesn't find what happens?

Comment: @agis `setInterval` will automatically execute every 500 ms until you call `clearInterval`. So if div is not found, clearInterval is not called and it'll keep executing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var time = setInterval(check, 100);

check = function()
{
    if ($("div").length > 0 )
    {
        //do something
        clearInterval (time); // clear countdown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it happens after a certain number of clicks you can monitor after every click on the page.

```
function checkIfDivExists () {
  if (document.querySelector('#your-div')) {
    // Stop monitoring
    document.removeEventListener('click', checkIfDivExists);
    // Do what you need to do
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', checkIfDivExists)
```

In this way you check only when it's necessary rather than trying several times each second, which will slow down the page.

Comment: I've tried to use this code but I get this result: "undefined". Am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you get it?

Comment: Tried it in Chrome console.

Comment: Sure, `document.addEventListener` returns `undefined` but when you click somewhere on the page the `checkIfDivExists` gets executed. Just put a `console.log('test')` inside the function body and you'll see that it gets called.

Comment: This will always be one ajax call behind

Comment: Actually it works, but not as I expect, it works just after I do an extra click after I see the div.

Comment: @agis...that is expected since the ajax is triggered by a click and ajax is asychronous

Comment: How can I do it to execute the console.log immediately when the div exists because otherwise it's not useful.

Comment: @agis what you really should do is check in the ajax success callback after data is inserted

Comment: You got me a little bit confused, how I might do this? The thing is that after few clicks my div appears and I want as soon as the div appears to do something, not how it is now, I don't want to do another click in order to do something.

Comment: Do you know where the AJAX call gets fired? Do you have something like `$.get` or `$.post` or `$.ajax` in your code?

Comment: @agis If you use mine or _metamask_'s answer you don't have to bother which method were used to insert the content

Comment: @LGSon your method for sure works, I'm just concerned about the performances and the overall approach. I guess agis is new to JS and it would be more valuable for him to learn a correct approach to react to asynchronous calls

Comment: @LGSon How drastically your method affects the perfomance of the website?

Comment: @agis Less than running a timer, more than catching the click for an ajax load (though nothing that will impact your site's overall experience).

Comment: Also, how can I do it the other way around, to check till the div doesn't exist anymore and then do something?